# проверочные слова к "деревенского"

Tags: орфография

проверочные слова к слову деревенского к обоим буквам

Comment: к обЕим буквам, а не обОим

Comment: Ему по барабану.

Answer (score 1):

Это невозможно, проверить можно только вторую гласную букву: деревенский-деревня, а первая Е непроверяемая.

Если Вы хотели проверить словом ДЕРЕВО, это неверно, потому что слово деревня образовалось от глагола "дерти, деру - драть".Деревня - расчищенное от растений место,потом крестьянский двор или хутор с участком пахотной земли

Answer (score 1):

Мнения ученых расходятся: Фасмер считает ошибочным сближение с *дерево*, Л. Куркина и Н. Шведова считают его обоснованным.

Правило такое:

[В исконно русских словах ***деревня, дерево, береза*** существует полногласие -ере-, зная о котором можно правильно написать эти слова.](http://russkiiyazyk.ru/orfografiya/pravopisanie/proverochnoe-slovo-k-slovu-derevnya.html)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Этимологический словарь школьника](http://www.pochemyneinache.com/alfavit/5/str101.html)

Comment: Полностью согласна, что исторически они от одного корня в индоевропейской давности, но мотивировать в совр. русском "Деревня - место, где растут деревья", как-то нелогично, связь полностью потеряна, а вот исторически поближе " деревня - сельская местность на освобождённой от деревьев местности, как бы выдранной" -логики больше, здесь корень угадывается, но всё равно исторический, а не современный. Проверить нельзя. Только проверить по словарю.